# OnTouchListener MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: gets only first view

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a grid of buttons in my activity. When the user slides their finger across this grid of buttons, I want all of the buttons touched to be essentially recorded so I know which buttons were touched.

I have been doing research on this and I do not see how this can be done, as most examples are with Bitmaps. The first view that it selected is the only one that is picked up from my `OnTouchListener`. From my readings, `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is what is to be used for this and I saw someone who said to use `view.getRawX()` and `view.getRawY()` but I don't understand how this would be used to determine which other buttons were pressed and which were not when the user is swiping their finger on the screen.

I am new to Android so my apologies if this is a much simpler task than I thought. Any input would be much appreciated as I wouldn't think this should be so complicated. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your View returns true to say that it's consuming the touch event, the rest of the views won't receive it. What you can do is make a custom `ViewGroup` (you say you have a grid, I'll just assume `GridView`?) that intercepts and handles all touch events:

```
public class InterceptingGridView extends GridView {
    private Rect mHitRect = new Rect();

    public InterceptingGridView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InterceptingGridView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
        //Always let the ViewGroup handle the event
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
        int x = Math.round(ev.getX());
        int y = Math.round(ev.getY());

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.getHitRect(mHitRect);

            if (mHitRect.contains(x, y)) {
                /*
                 * Dispatch the event to the containing child. Note that using this
                 * method, children are not guaranteed to receive ACTION_UP, ACTION_CANCEL,
                 * or ACTION_DOWN events and should handle the case where only an ACTION_MOVE is received.
                 */
                child.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        }

        //Make sure to still call through to the superclass, so that
        //the ViewGroup still functions normally (e.g. scrolling)
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

How you choose to handle the event depends on the logic that you require, but the takeaway is to let the container view consume all of the touch events, and let it handle dispatching the events to the children.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what this is doing because most of the terminology I have not seen before. I am new to Android and Java (having only worked in C++ before), my apologies!

Comment: Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

Comment: Oh boy, this will take a while to figure out. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);


        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {

            }
            break;
        }

        return true;

}
```

it works for multitouch