# ACTION_MOVE returns the same value every time it is called in OnTouch

Tags: java, android, ontouch

I'm trying to call a method to update a tts element with a different value every time the `ACTION_MOVE` is called. However, it returns the same value every time it is called. The `respondCoordinates(v)` method has an `if` statement to change the value.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //_gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    int eventAction = event.getAction();

    // you may need the x/y location
    int x = (int)event.getRawX();
    int y = (int)event.getRawY();

    Point boardPos = getBoardIndexX(new Point(x,y));
    // put your code in here to handle the event
    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            Log.d("Chess", "Down: " + x + ", " + y + " [" + boardPos.x + ", " + boardPos.y + "]");
            if(OnBoard(boardPos))
            {
                // then play
                lastPlayTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                lastPlayPos.x = boardPos.x;
                lastPlayPos.y = boardPos.y;
                respondCoordinates(v);

            }

            break;//return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("Chess", "Up: " + x + ", " + y + " [" + boardPos.x + ", " + boardPos.y + "]");
            lastPlayPos.x = -1;
            lastPlayPos.y = -1;

            v.performClick();
            break;//return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(boardPos.x != lastPlayPos.x || boardPos.y != lastPlayPos.y) {
                // then we're on a new square
                Log.d("Chess", "Move: " + x + ", " + y + " [" + boardPos.x + ", " + boardPos.y + "]");
                lastPlayPos.x = boardPos.x;
                lastPlayPos.y = boardPos.y;

                if(OnBoard(boardPos))
                {
                    // then play
                    lastPlayTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    respondCoordinates(v);
                }
            }
    }
    // tell the View to redraw the Canvas
    //invalidate();

    return true;//super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void respondCoordinates(View v) {

    int iTo = getIndexOfButton(v);

    String join = "";
    String letter = "";
    String number = "";
    String piece = "";


    if ((iTo >= 0) && (iTo <= 7)) {
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }
        number = "8";
        if (iTo == 0) {
            letter = "a";


        } else if (iTo == 1) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 2) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 3) {
            letter = "d";

        } else if (iTo == 4) {
            letter = "e";

        } else if (iTo == 5) {
            letter = "f";

        } else if (iTo == 6) {
            letter = "g";

        } else if (iTo == 7) {
            letter = "h";

        }

    } else if ((iTo >= 8) && (iTo <= 15)) {
        number = "7";
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }

        if (iTo == 8) {
            letter = "a";
        } else if (iTo == 9) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 10) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 11) {
            letter = "d";
        } else if (iTo == 12) {
            letter = "e";
        } else if (iTo == 13) {
            letter = "f";
        } else if (iTo == 14) {
            letter = "g";
        } else if (iTo == 15) {
            letter = "h";
        }


    } else if ((iTo >= 16) && (iTo <= 23)) {
        number = "6";
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }

        if (iTo == 16) {
            letter = "a";
        } else if (iTo == 17) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 18) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 19) {
            letter = "d";
        } else if (iTo == 20) {
            letter = "e";
        } else if (iTo == 21) {
            letter = "f";
        } else if (iTo == 22) {
            letter = "g";
        } else if (iTo == 23) {
            letter = "h";
        }


    } else if ((iTo >= 24) && (iTo <= 31)) {
        number = "5";
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }

        if (iTo == 24) {
            letter = "a";
        } else if (iTo == 25) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 26) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 27) {
            letter = "d";
        } else if (iTo == 28) {
            letter = "e";
        } else if (iTo == 29) {
            letter = "f";
        } else if (iTo == 30) {
            letter = "g";
        } else if (iTo == 31) {
            letter = "h";
        }


    } else if ((iTo >= 32) && (iTo <= 39)) {
        number = "4";
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }

        if (iTo == 32) {
            letter = "a";
        } else if (iTo == 33) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 34) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 35) {
            letter = "d";
        } else if (iTo == 36) {
            letter = "e";
        } else if (iTo == 37) {
            letter = "f";
        } else if (iTo == 38) {
            letter = "g";
        } else if (iTo == 39) {
            letter = "h";
        }


    } else if ((iTo >= 40) && (iTo <= 47)) {
        number = "3";
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }

        if (iTo == 40) {
            letter = "a";
        } else if (iTo == 41) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 42) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 43) {
            letter = "d";
        } else if (iTo == 44) {
            letter = "e";
        } else if (iTo == 45) {
            letter = "f";
        } else if (iTo == 46) {
            letter = "g";
        } else if (iTo == 47) {
            letter = "h";
        }


    } else if ((iTo >= 48) && (iTo <= 55)) {
        number = "2";
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }

        if (iTo == 48) {
            letter = "a";
        } else if (iTo == 49) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 50) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 51) {
            letter = "d";
        } else if (iTo == 52) {
            letter = "e";
        } else if (iTo == 53) {
            letter = "f";
        } else if (iTo == 54) {
            letter = "g";
        } else if (iTo == 55) {
            letter = "h";
        }


    } else if ((iTo >= 56) && (iTo <= 63)) {
        number = "1";
        if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.PAWN) {
            piece = "Pawn";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.BISHOP) {
            piece = "Bishop";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.ROOK) {
            piece = "Rook";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KNIGHT) {
            piece = "Knight";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.QUEEN) {
            piece = "Queen";
        } else if (_jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.WHITE, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING || _jni.pieceAt(BoardConstants.BLACK, iTo) == BoardConstants.KING) {
            piece = "King";
        }

        if (iTo == 56) {
            letter = "a";
        } else if (iTo == 57) {
            letter = "b";
        } else if (iTo == 58) {
            letter = "c";
        } else if (iTo == 59) {
            letter = "d";
        } else if (iTo == 60) {
            letter = "e";
        } else if (iTo == 61) {
            letter = "f";
        } else if (iTo == 62) {
            letter = "g";
        } else if (iTo == 63) {
            letter = "h";
        }
    }

    join = letter + number + "" + piece;

    //Log.d("Chess", join);

    _chessActivity.soundNotification(join);


}


public int getIndexOfButton(View but){
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        if(_arrImages[i] == ((ChessImageView)but)){

            _arrImages[i].setPressed(false);
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I should note that action_down produces the correct value every time so it is nothing to do with the method that I have created

Comment: It looks like it has *everything* to do with the `respondCoordinates()` method. You mention that `ACTION_DOWN` produces the correct values, but the correct values of what? `x` and `y`? But the `respondCoordinates()` method does not take the `x` and `y` coordinates, it takes the `View`; so if that method is producing the wrong value, it seems that it must be causing the issue. I recommend posting the `respondCoordinates()` method, and going a little more in-depth on what exactly it is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Bryan I have attached the respondcoordinates(v) code. What I'm trying to do is assign a letter, number and piece to the different button views on the screen. Then return it to the onTouch so that the user can drag their finger across the screen and it will read out the different positions on the chess board

Comment: Each button has a value from 0 to 63, sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: That won't help for your issue, but I think your code would have been clearer if you used a modulo based formule instead of your elsif structure for your letter and number. Something like number = String.valueOf(8 - (iTo / 8)) and letter = Character.toString((char) ((iTo % 8) + 97))

Comment: The `respondCoordinates()` method only returns a `Boolean`, it always returns `false`, and you never use the return value in the `onTouch` method. What exactly are you trying to "return to the `onTouch`"?

Comment: Actually looking at it it seems like I'm not actually trying to return anything, I just want it to continuously call the method to read out the different values of the chess board. Should I be returning the String value then call the _chessActivity.soundNotification(join); from the OnTouch?

Comment: What for? It looks like the method should actually return `void`. From what I understand, you want the user to be able to "hover" over each of the pieces, and as it passes over a new piece a sound is played. Then your issue is that it is not creating the correct notification sound?

Comment: It looks like the `getIndexOfButton()` method is your real issue.

Comment: If you don't want to return anything declare your method void instead of boolean and remove your return false.

Comment: Yeah it continues to return the same cell as you drag across. I'll upload the getIndexOfButton method

Comment: What `View` did you set the `OnTouchListener` to? And is the `getIndexOfButton()` method returning `-1` each time?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with getIndexOfButton, but with the implementation of OnTouchListener, I think it is intended that you still get the first view you touched until ACTION_UP.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
   //_arrImages[i].setOnClickListener(ocl);
   //_arrImages[i].setFocusable(false);
   //_arrImages[i].setOnLongClickListener(olcl);
   _arrImages[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
   _arrImgCache[i] = new ImageCacheObject();
  }

Comment: Yes it returns -1 each time

Comment: But I think Damien may be right. It is fine returning the view on ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the issue correctly. You are assuming that the `View` passed to `onTouch` is one of the 64 views on the chessboard, but this is not the case. The `View` passed to `onTouch` is the `View` that you set the `OnTouchListener` on. Which, in this case, is the chessboard itself.

Instead, you should be finding the index of the individual piece by using the coordinates of the `MotionEvent`. The method should look something like this:

```
private int mLastChildIndex = -1;

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getRawX();
    int y = (int) event.getRawY();

    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastChildIndex = getChildIndex((ViewGroup) view, x, y);
            playNotificationForIndex(mLastChildIndex);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int currentIndex = getChildIndex((ViewGroup) view, x, y);
            if (currentIndex != mLastChildIndex) {
                playNotificationForIndex(currentIndex);
                mLastChildIndex = currentIndex;
            } break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            performClickForIndex(mLastChildIndex);
            mLastChildIndex = -1;
            break;
    }

    return true; // This method eats all MotionEvent actions for the View
}

private int getChildIndex(ViewGroup viewGroup, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        int[] coordinates = new int[2];
        child.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);

        Rect bounds = new Rect(coordinates[0], coordinates[1],
                coordinates[0] + child.getWidth(), coordinates[1] + child.getHeight());
        if (bounds.contains(x, y)) {
            return i;
        }
    } return -1;
}
```

Comment: My supervisor told me the exact same thing just before you did. Spot on, you are correct

Answer (score 0):

That needs to be checked but I believe that if you leave a view before an ACTION_UP, you still get an ACTION_MOVE for that view, so your view v is always the one you had your ACTION_DOWN on, even if you move on another one.

This is probably the intended behaviour.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312276/ontouchlistener-motionevent-action-move-gets-only-first-view) might confirm it. Their solution might not fit your situation though, since you would get an output for all the views you touched instead of only the current one.

This is anoying but I think the solution is to have one listener on the grid and not on the cells, and to find which cell you are touching from x and y.